# I would like to make the following psql query faster

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum FROM table
    WHERE user = $1 AND bool_val != True) x WHERE rownum = ANY($2)
```

However if i want the 170000th rownum returned, the query takes about a whole minute and i would like to reduce this time. Is there anyway of speeding this up?

Comment: Show full definition of table and current explain/query plans

Comment: How much stuff is in that $2 parameter? =ANY() uses linear search through the array, so if the array is huge, it will be slow. Please give examples of values for $2 that are slow, also your usual number of values in the array, and min/max values.

Comment: Another thing that would slow it down is the SELECT * inside the subquery if the table has lots of columns. It could be faster to just select the primary key for rows that you're interested in, then join back to the table to get them. But that's not possible to know without more info.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` already by the indexed primary key, then your current call to `ROW_NUMBER` should actually already be efficient.  But, we might be able to do better with the following composite index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (user, bool_val, id);
```

This index, if used, should help to speed up the filtering process in the inner `WHERE` clause.  It also covers `id`, so that the index alone can be used to compute the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Probably should've mentioned that I already have that index created.

Comment: Do you have this _exact_ index, or just one or more indices similar to it?

Comment: Well mine is CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (user, id, bool_val); 
Does the order have any effect?

Comment: @user15178581  Yes, it matters a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL planner lacks the brains to stop the query early once rownum exceeds the highest value in `$2`.  You can build that knowledge into the query yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum FROM table
    WHERE user = $1 AND bool_val != True ORDER BY id LiMIT highest_value_in_dollar2) x 
WHERE rownum = ANY($2)
```

This would be especially important if the number of rows in x would otherwise be much greater than 170,000 (or whatever highest_value_in_dollar2 is).  It will also pair well with the index Tim proposed.